# redirect non existing subdomains to www subdomain but not existing ones

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect non existing domains to *www* subdomain but at the same time not redirecting existing subdomains. For example:

```
domain.com --> www.domain.com
existingsubdomain.domain.com --> existingsubdomain.domain.com
nonexistingsubdomain.domain.com --> www.domain.com
```

So far I have been able to find examples only for redirecting everything (even existing ones), what I need is everything (to *www*) + exceptions (existing subdomains)

I'm working with apache `.htaccess`, how would such a rule look like?

I found an example that supposedly does this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it only does this:

```
nonexistingsubdomain.domain.com --> www.nonexistingsubdomain.domain.com
```

Comment: That depends on how you have structured you subdomains server side. E.g. you would have a `VirtualHost` for each sub domain and a _catch all_ fallback with `*.domain.com` where you then do a redirect `www.domain.com` if it is required. But as said that heavily depends on how you structure your subdomains on the server.

Comment: Btw if you ask questions make sure that you check the formatting in the preview so that it is readable ( e.g. that you add the required line breaks to that the code blocks are highlighted.)

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com
```

?